# Control Calendar Overlay with Master Calendar

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar, overlay

I am trying to make a master calendar that not only views multiple lower level calendar's, but also can affect change to the overlay calendars.

The best example I can think of would be to say, I have an event for 5 people. All of there calendar's are connected to my calendar and I have permission to add an event to there calendar. Can I change all five at once using my master calendar?

Answer (score 0):

I have come a crossed this issue in the past. By OOTB you can view calendars from other site collections and roll them up into one view however having an addition flow from the master calendar to other calendars would require the item be created on the master calendar and a column that denotes the other calendars created. ex column location calendar would have the choices Hawaii, Connecticut, Florida, Georgia.

After that has been completed you will need to set up a workflow that copies or moves that item to the other calendar based off an if statement. If Hawaii then move / copy list item to list for Hawaii calendar.

I hope I didn't confuse you. Please see this link for more information.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f67f0372-863d-44d3-8875-4f0a02b726be/copy-item-from-one-list-to-other-using-sharepoint-2010-workflow?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious